# Create an activity when a specific profile is submitted?

Tags: api, profile, activities

I'm sending out a profile to contacts with a checksum - they are not logged in when they submit it.
Can i create an activity for that contact when the profile form is submitted?
So far i've run into permissions problems - i'm probably not using the API correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) extension to create activity when a profile is submitted. Or you can write a extension to use [post hook](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_post/) for 'Profile' Object and then use Activity create api to create Activity(Note: you might need to pass check_permission to FALSE in api params to bypass permission)

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks, Rules looks like a good starting point for me, will try it out.

Comment: All the best :)

Comment: How can you create a CiviRule that triggers on profile submission? It does not appear to be listed as a trigger?

Comment: Does this work on WordPress, or is custom extension the only option. And does CiviRules have a specific CONDITION that triggers only if Profile XYZ was the one that submitted?

Comment: There isn't any condition specific to the profile submission. However, when a profile is submitted contact created or updated trigger is invoked so you can use these triggers but there isn't a way to control the trigger based on profile id. Implementing via an extension using hooks would be viable.

Comment: I still do not see this as an option in civirules. Is there any extensions available?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal sites could do this via webform_civicrm. The module works with links using checksums.

Comment: Yes agreed, Webform CiviCRM is an good alternative.